# Rails 4 - Destroy deleting different ID to what is in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to delete a notice/post, I get the following:

```
Started DELETE "/notices/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-22 17:34:46 +0800
Processing by NoticesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "id"=>"8"}
  Notice Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "notices".* FROM "notices" WHERE (8) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "notices" WHERE "notices"."id" = ?  [["id", 7]]
   (4.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/notices?edit_mode=true
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
```

So I have just passed in the ID to be 8, however it deletes ID 7 and I don't know why.

The controller looks like:

```
class NoticesController < ApplicationController
 def destroy
  @notice = Notice.find_by(params[:id])
  @notice.destroy
  redirect_to :back
 end
end
```

The view template where the delete link looks like:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", notice_path(@notice.id), class: "button", method: :delete %>
```

I have no idea why it isn't working.
I have restarted the server, thinking that it might be a routing issue, however the error still persist. Any ideas?

Also, if I left out any information, please tell me. This is my first question.

Comment: I don't know how you manage your Notice objects, but if you are on the edit page, click on the destroy button, then it will redirect you to `:back`, which is the edit page of the destroyed object => 404 Not Found

Comment: @MrYoshiji agreed.  `Notice` model has something to do here?

Comment: Can you post your notice model and routes related to this?

Comment: Does it work in the console?  You can use `rails c --sandbox` so it rollsback anything deleted when you exit the console.  As per Shamsul's answer it should be `find` not `find_by` - you can see the SQL select statement you currently have is wrong; it's effectively just getting you the first record.

Comment: You are using `find_by` where you want to use `find`.

Comment: please post ur routes file i think you have write somthing like resource :notices.

Comment: what database you are using ? postgresql ?? mysql ?? etc ??

Comment: Hi guys, the issue was that I didn't setup the controller correctly just as Shamsul, Graeme and zwippie said. Thank you for you time at looking at my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the controller as:-

```
class NoticesController < ApplicationController
 def destroy
  @notice = Notice.find(params[:id])
  @notice.destroy
  redirect_to :action => "index"
 end
end
```

In the view:-

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @notice, class: "button", method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Still deleting the wrong ID. I would put the logs here but I can't...

Comment: Sorry, now I get - No route matches [DELETE] "/notices". Also it appears that no params are being sent to say "delete this ID"

Comment: Hi Shamsul, you were correct. the issue was Notice.find(params[:id]). I am not sure why it didn't work when you first said told me the solution but it works now.

Comment: if a answer works then it should be either accepted or it should be voted up so that other knows it is correct. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry, new to this. Just accepted it. Thanks for your feedback